# Why don't my unit tests run in Python?

Tags: python

I have

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    lib.py
    tests/
        lib_test.py
```

In lib_test.py I have:

```
import lib
```

When running from myapp:

```
python tests/lib_test.py
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: No module named lib
```

It's some sort of beginner error no doubt.  However I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to do `import lib` like you have above, Python tries to find the import, starting with the directory you are in (so, for example, if you were right in the `myapp` directory, it would find `lib.py` and be able to `import lib`).  However, when importing within a package (basically, anything with `__init__.py`) you should go towards using explicit package imports (like `from myapp import lib`) so that the python interpreter will know where to look. This also has the advantage of avoiding namespace collisions with `lib` (i.e., if you were in a different folder that had `lib.py` in it).

Bottom line: replace `import lib` with `from myapp import lib` and you'll be good.

Comment: Personally, I have a preference for [relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/): `from .. import lib`. This requires an `__init__.py` file in the `tests` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `__init__.py` file in `tests/` directory.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent suggestion.  Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Could you please try this  "from myapp import lib" in lib_test.py file.